# White strip on WP site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, frontend

Сan you help me remove a white strip of a few pixels due to which a scrollbar appears below ?

Thank you very much and sorry for my English. Please correct me !

[Link to the site](http://148.251.86.250/main-shop/)

[Sreenshort of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2SkL.png)

Comment: You should try to provide a [mcve]. If you don't know what can cause the problem, the thing to do is to start removing elements from the page until the problem goes away; then the last thing you removed is the cause! Then when you're still unsure, post that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Breadcrumb Style has few issues with CSS. Please copy the below code and past into the Customizer ->Additional CSS :

```
.breadcrumbs {
    width: 100% !important; 
 }
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS You have

```
html.html-has-lrm
{
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

change that to

```
html.html-has-lrm 
{
 overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

and your white strip will no longer be visible..

as i can see you are using caching plugin so don't forget to clear the cache after making changes..